# Batch raster calculation of slope and aspect in SAGA

Tags: saga, batch

I am relatively new to the SAGA software, I have only used it for small amouns of data, and for basic calculations. 
My data is obtained by mapping certain areas in GoogleEarth, then, overlaying the poligons with DEM data, then exporting as a raster grid of cells.

The problem is that I have to obtain the slope and mean aspect for a series (more than 1000) of rasters (grid) in SAGA. Slope is calculated in the morphometry tab, but for the aspect (mean of horizontal angles), I have to do a series of operations:

1. Import my grid;
2. Calculate slope, aspect in the Morphometry tab (that aspect is not what I need)
3. Creating a constant grid based on the initial imported grid;
4. Zonal Grid Statistics, based on the imported raster grid, the constant grid and the aspect raster from Morphometry)

With these  operations I get the correct value for mean aspect of my raster grid in a resulting table.

I am searching for methods of doing these operations all at once for my >1000 raster grids, because it would greatly reduce my working effort. I have recently found about batch operations with SAGA, but I have little programming knowledge, and I thought if this would help me.

Is it possible to do these operations with batch SAGA?

Do you know alternatives to SAGA batch?